# Want a good database that has precise location coordinates (longitude & latitude)

Tags: data, latitude-longitude

I am searching for a good Excel spreadsheet database in tabular form that has the following:

1) It can be related to anything, eg. monuments of a country, tourist places, wildlife, cities; anything that forms a group and can be plotted on a map.

2) It should have over 300 entries.

3) It would be nice if the database/table has attributes other than name, latitude, and longitude.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Have you searched the internet yet? This doesn't sound like it should be too hard to find, but this kind of question is considered too broad for this forum.

Comment: how about geonames.org

Comment: @john I have searched and found data related to cities only which doesn't have attributes other than location coordinates and name of the city/country..I want something more interesting ...since this was a forum of geographers I thought someone out there might have come across such a database ...The other attributes that I am talking about can be a small description, image url etc..It's difficult to find such a database having over 300 or even 200 rows..

Comment: @john I would like to give a little more description of what I am trying to do with this database. I will implement a Steganography tool that can hide text message inside a map : to a normal user it appears a map but actually it carries a hidden message behind it for example "Scarlette is very Pretty" will be depicted by that map.

Comment: There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you can use to improve it with such clarifications rather than creating a comment trail that potential answerers may or may not read.

Comment: So I'll be the pedantic one: a spreadsheet isn't a database, you're just looking for a dataset. It sounds like you want points, since you want a specific lat/lon. Your question title says precise - to how many decimal places, or do you just mean points not areas? [GNIS placenames](http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/download_data.htm) come to mind. It really shouldn't be too hard to break 300 records, though finding the additional attributes you want might be more difficult. "Interesting" is fairly subjective.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out Geonames. Get one of the [country files](http://www.geonames.org/countries/) which has different files on different themes.